# Make an utility with automator which opens a specific folder with terminal and runs the 'compass watch' script

Tags: terminal, watch, automator, compass, utility

I have this automator setup which allows you to open a folder with terminal. The thing I want is that after the folder is opened via terminal, it should run the `compass watch` script.

This is what I currently have but I don't seem to find the solution myself. I tried adding some applescript and some bash, but nothing seems to work. Anyone know the solution?

[image: Finder open with terminal utility]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Add the "**Run AppleScript**" action in your workflow

If the `compass watch` script is a file, use this **AppleScript** script

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set compasswatchScript to quoted form of "" -- drag drop the script file between double quote
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script compasswatchScript in window 1
    end tell
end run
```

Insert the path of your script file in the second line of this script

--

if `compass watch` is a command, use this **AppleScript** script

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "compass watch" in window 1
    end tell
end run
```